# WPF development tools

Tags: .net, wpf

I want to develop a WPF application(like weather report) with good look and feel. So what  tools do i use? 
like

1.Visual Studio express 2012
 
2.Expression Blend
 
3.Expression Design

is any one of the above enough or need more than one tool?

Comment: VS2012 will be enough for coding. You'll need some graphic software for images/icons but I think that 90% of good look&feel rely on programmer ability to design a great UX.

Answer (score 1):

You just need VS 2012 & Blend as a programmer since it covers all your needs. But if your designs aren't delivered and you need to create them yourself Expression Design or Photoshop might do the trick.